# Subquery join and total dilemma again

Tags: mysql, join, sum

So here is my latest endeaver .. trying to add the result of sub queries to get another field or total... but sumhow this *simple* syntax doesn't seem to work.. can somebody please point me to the right direction... thanks in advance

```
    SELECT 
    sub_events.name AS sub_event, 
    clients.name AS client, 
    divisions.name AS division, 
    subdivisions.name AS subdivision, 
    (SELECT CONCAT(name,' ',surname) FROM users WHERE id = bookings.host_id) AS host,
    CONCAT(users.name,'  ',users.surname) AS name, 
    (SELECT client_cost FROM itineraries WHERE itinerary_type_id = 1 AND itinerary_booking_id = 1 AND booking_id = bookings.id AND client_cost IS NOT NULL) AS flight, 
    (SELECT client_cost FROM itineraries WHERE itinerary_type_id = 1 and itinerary_booking_id = 2 AND booking_id = bookings.id AND client_cost IS NOT NULL) AS flight_change, 
    (SELECT client_cost FROM itineraries WHERE itinerary_type_id = 2 AND itinerary_booking_id = 1 AND booking_id = bookings.id AND client_cost IS NOT NULL) AS hotel, 
    (SELECT client_cost FROM itineraries WHERE itinerary_type_id = 2 and itinerary_booking_id = 3 AND booking_id = bookings.id AND client_cost IS NOT NULL) AS hotel_change, 
    (SELECT client_cost FROM itineraries WHERE itinerary_type_id = 3  AND itinerary_booking_id = 1 AND booking_id = bookings.id AND client_cost IS NOT NULL)  AS transfer, 
    (SELECT client_cost FROM itineraries WHERE itinerary_type_id = 3 AND itinerary_booking_id = 4 AND booking_id = bookings.id AND client_cost IS NOT NULL) AS transfer_change
    (SELECT SUM((SELECT client_cost FROM itineraries WHERE itinerary_type_id = 3 AND itinerary_booking_id = 4 AND booking_id = bookings.id AND client_cost IS NOT NULL)
            +(SELECT client_cost FROM itineraries WHERE itinerary_type_id = 1 and itinerary_booking_id = 2 AND booking_id = bookings.id AND client_cost IS NOT NULL)
            +(SELECT client_cost FROM itineraries WHERE itinerary_type_id = 2 AND itinerary_booking_id = 1 AND booking_id = bookings.id AND client_cost IS NOT NULL)
            +(SELECT client_cost FROM itineraries WHERE itinerary_type_id = 2 and itinerary_booking_id = 3 AND booking_id = bookings.id AND client_cost IS NOT NULL)
            +(SELECT client_cost FROM itineraries WHERE itinerary_type_id = 3  AND itinerary_booking_id = 1 AND booking_id = bookings.id AND client_cost IS NOT NULL)
            +(SELECT client_cost FROM itineraries WHERE itinerary_type_id = 3 AND itinerary_booking_id = 4 AND booking_id = bookings.id AND client_cost IS NOT NULL)) AS Total)
FROM users 
JOIN bookings ON bookings.guest_id = users.id 
JOIN clients ON users.client_id = bookings.client_id 
JOIN details ON details.user_id = users.id 
JOIN divisions ON divisions.client_id = users.client_id 
JOIN subdivisions ON subdivisions.division_id = bookings.division_id 
JOIN sub_events ON sub_events.id = bookings.sub_event_id 
JOIN itineraries ON itineraries.booking_id = bookings.id 
GROUP BY bookings.id`
```

Comment: What specifically doesn't work?

Comment: I can't get the sum of the subqueries...

Comment: When you use SUM and GROUP BY, you need to list all the columns that aren't aggregated in the GROUP BY clause. MySQL provides a non-standard extension to GROUP BY called hidden columns. But it's really very hard to use.  Read and understand this web page http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html before you try to debug your query.

Comment: This is a horrible query, and would perform like crap due to the large number of corelated subqueries. You could achieve all this with a simple join to `itineraries` and a few `if` or `case` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `SUM()`, you just want to add them:

```
... AS transfer_change,
(SELECT client_cost FROM itineraries ...) +
(SELECT client_cost FROM itineraries ...) +
... +
(SELECT client_cost FROM itineraries ...) AS Total
```

However, this is a horrible query, and would perform like crap due to the large number of corelated subqueries. You could achieve all this with a simple join to itineraries and a few `sum()` of values based on `if` or `case` statements.

Comment: I agree.. its really crappy .. can anyone come up with the better version of it?? would be really help ful.... Thankyou!